# error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, std

I am trying to add a std::function to std::thread and i stumble upon this error

```
error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
```

```
struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(const std::function<void(int)>& tfunc)
        : thread(tfunc) { //<----- error points here
        thread.join();
    }

    std::thread thread;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `thread(tfunc)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver that was the first thing i tried but the error is the same

Comment: Initial integer value is missing when thread ctor is called: `thread(std::ref(tfunc), 123)`. Function of thread body takes integer, you need to provide it when thread starts.

Comment: @rafix07 Of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial integer value is missing when thread ctor is called: thread(std::ref(tfunc), 123).

Function of thread body takes integer, you need to provide it when thread starts.