# error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments [...] but the number of arguments is correct

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int num_of_threads = 4;

// Simple function for incrementing an atomic int
void work(std::atomic<int>& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        a++;
    }
}

void test() {
    std::atomic<int> a;
    a = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(num_of_threads);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_of_threads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(work, a); //<- here is the issue
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
136 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
```

I also looked up this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291698/error-static-assertion-failed-stdthread-arguments-must-be-invocable-after-co) but I'm sure that the number of my arguments is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a thread, its arguments are copied, and that leads to problem for thread-functions taking references as arguments.

You need to wrap objects that you want to pass as references, using [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) (or `std::cref` for references to constants):

```
threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(a));
```